# AWS CDK (Python): Ephemeral storage via bind mount and permissions

Tags: aws-cdk

I would like mount some ephemeral storage using Python AWS CDK definitions. This is for a Fargate based ECS container using Node (NPM) and needing some scratch space (the root fs is read-only). However Node doesn't run with it as it currently stands due to be being root owned.

Currently I'm doing the following:

```py
task = ecs.FargateTaskDefinition(
    main,
    "FargateServiceTaskDef",
    cpu="512",
    # ... other options
)

container = task.add_container(
    "web",
    image=image,
    # ... other options
)

# Somewhere below in mount_points or add_volume is there a way to set permissions or mount point UID ownership?
container.add_mount_points(
    ecs.MountPoint(
        container_path="/home/node/.npm", source_volume="npm-scratch", read_only=False
    )
)

task_definition.add_volume(name="npm-scratch")
```

The error at container startup:

```
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /home/node/.npm/_cacache
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR! sudo chown -R 1000:1000 "/home/node/.npm"
```

Or am I taking the wrong approach trying to set the mount point permissions or UID?

Comment: I have worked around this by specifying .npmrc use `/tmp` as a cache location instead of using ephemeral storage. However, I would still like to know how to set permissions (via CDK) on ephemeral storage in case future needs require more or faster storage via EBS.

Comment: Actually, it seems even /tmp ends up being read-only.